# codeigniter upload files from multiple input

Tags: codeigniter, upload

i want to upload files with multiple input. I have tried the code below, but the files not uploaded, and i cant get the upload directory.

HTML

```
<input type="file" name="userfile[]" size="20" />
```

Controller

```
public function detailTugasInput($idKelas,$id){
    $this->load->model('tugass');
    $records = $_FILES['userfile'];
    //var_dump($records); die();
    $config['upload_path']          = './file/';
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'pdf|doc|txt|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']             = 0;
    $config['max_width']            = 1024;
    $config['max_height']           = 768;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    foreach ($_FILES as $key => $value) {
        $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
        $file_ary = array(
        'nama_kembali' => $value['name'],
        'file_kembali' => $value['tmp_name']
        );
    }
}
```

And i also tried to get the uploaded data with this code below, but why always appear error?

```
$checked_arr = $_POST['userfile'];
```

Comment: Have you used `enctype=multipart/form-data` in `form` tag? e.g. `<form action="<form_action_url>" method="<form_method>" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: yes i already used it

Comment: are you getting values in the `$records`?

Comment: yes, i tried to getting the values into $records but i cant get the uploaded directory from it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Below Codes

`HTML` :

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="userfile[]" multiple />
```

`Controller` :

```
public function detailTugasInput($idKelas, $id){

    $this->load->model('tugass');

    if(!empty($_FILES['userfile']['name'])) {

        $filesCount = count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

        for($i = 0; $i < $filesCount; $i++) {

            $_FILES['userFile']['name'] = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i];
            $_FILES['userFile']['type'] = $_FILES['userfile']['type'][$i];
            $_FILES['userFile']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $_FILES['userFile']['error'] = $_FILES['userfile']['error'][$i];
            $_FILES['userFile']['size'] = $_FILES['userfile']['size'][$i];

            $config['upload_path'] = './file/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf|doc|txt|jpg|png';

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $this->upload->initialize($config);

            $this->upload->do_upload('userFile');
            if($this->upload->do_upload('userFile')){
                $fileData = $this->upload->data();
                $uploadData[$i]['file_name'] = $fileData['file_name'];
                $uploadData[$i]['created'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                $uploadData[$i]['modified'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

For more Support, [Check This](http://www.codexworld.com/codeigniter-upload-multiple-files-images/)

Comment: It's works!! thanks!! but how can i get the uploaded directory?

Comment: `$config['upload_path']` stores the path where files are uploaded

Comment: i mean after i upload the files, how can i store each uploaded path to database?